# WPF Update UserControl when item has been added from other user control

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am working on WPF project using MVVM and I have an issue that I am sure someone came across..
I have a MainWindow in which I am loading UserControl1 In UserControl1, I have a hyperlink which opens the Modal window and in which, I load UserControl2 as modal. Both UserControls has their own view models. Now from second view model, I want to trigger a PropertyChangednotification to a collection in view model of a UserControl1? How can I achieve that?

what I am trying to accomplish is: I have a combobox on UserControl1 that needs to be updated when item is added from UserControl2.

I am using the following class and both viewmodels inherits the follwoing class:

```
public abstract class PropertyChangedNotification : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        #region Fields

        private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        #endregion

        #region Protected

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the value of a property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property value.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="propertySelector">Expression tree contains the property definition.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The property value.</param>
        protected void SetValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertySelector, T value)
        {
            string propertyName = GetPropertyName(propertySelector);

            SetValue<T>(propertyName, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the value of a property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property value.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The property value.</param>
        protected void SetValue<T>(string propertyName, T value)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);
            }

            _values[propertyName] = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value of a property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property value.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="propertySelector">Expression tree contains the property definition.</param>
        /// <returns>The value of the property or default value if not exist.</returns>
        protected T GetValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertySelector)
        {
            string propertyName = GetPropertyName(propertySelector);

            return GetValue<T>(propertyName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value of a property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property value.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property.</param>
        /// <returns>The value of the property or default value if not exist.</returns>
        protected T GetValue<T>(string propertyName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);
            }

            object value;
            if (!_values.TryGetValue(propertyName, out value))
            {
                value = default(T);
                _values.Add(propertyName, value);
            }

            return (T)value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Validates current instance properties using Data Annotations.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">This instance property to validate.</param>
        /// <returns>Relevant error string on validation failure or <see cref="System.String.Empty"/> on validation success.</returns>
        protected virtual string OnValidate(string propertyName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);
            }

            string error = string.Empty;
            var value = GetValue(propertyName);
            var results = new List<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult>(1);
            var result = Validator.TryValidateProperty(
                value,
                new ValidationContext(this, null, null)
                {
                    MemberName = propertyName
                },
                results);

            if (!result)
            {
                var validationResult = results.First();
                error = validationResult.ErrorMessage;
            }

            return error;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Change Notification

        /// <summary>
        /// Raised when a property on this object has a new value.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertySelector)
        {
            var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
            if (propertyChanged != null)
            {
                string propertyName = GetPropertyName(propertySelector);
                propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        #region Data Validation

        string IDataErrorInfo.Error
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("IDataErrorInfo.Error is not supported, use IDataErrorInfo.this[propertyName] instead.");
            }
        }

        string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                return OnValidate(propertyName);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Privates

        private string GetPropertyName(LambdaExpression expression)
        {
            var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExpression == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            return memberExpression.Member.Name;
        }

        private object GetValue(string propertyName)
        {
            object value;
            if (!_values.TryGetValue(propertyName, out value))
            {
                var propertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType()).Find(propertyName, false);
                if (propertyDescriptor == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);
                }

                value = propertyDescriptor.GetValue(this);
                _values.Add(propertyName, value);
            }
            var propertyDescriptor1 = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType()).Find(propertyName, false);
            if (propertyDescriptor1 == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);
            }

            value = propertyDescriptor1.GetValue(this);
            return value;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Debugging

        /// <summary>
        /// Warns the developer if this object does not have
        /// a public property with the specified name. This
        /// method does not exist in a Release build.
        /// </summary>
        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
        {
            // Verify that the property name matches a real, 
            // public, instance property on this object.
            if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
            {
                string msg = "Invalid property name: " + propertyName;

                if (this.ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName)
                    throw new Exception(msg);
                else
                    Debug.Fail(msg);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns whether an exception is thrown, or if a Debug.Fail() is used
        /// when an invalid property name is passed to the VerifyPropertyName method.
        /// The default value is false, but subclasses used by unit tests might
        /// override this property's getter to return true.
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual bool ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName { get; private set; }

        #endregion // Debugging Aides
    }
```

UserControl1 is an investment control and user control 2 is an institution control as seen below in screenshot

[image: investment control]
[image: institution control]

When someone clicks on "Add New" it opens the Institution control in a modal window..
investment user control bound to investmentViewModel and institution control bound to institutionViewModel.
When I click on Save changes on modal, it will trigger propertyChangeNotification on institutionViewModel and not the investmentViewModel.

Comment: Why?  If the collection *has* changed, then you have no need.  If it *hasn't* changed, firing the event will have no effect.  Oh, wait, you've got a non-observable collection in an INPC property, don't you?  You should make your collections implement INotifyCollectionChanged or be ObservableCollection<T>.  Collection properties should normally be read-only.

Comment: Also, if instance A needs to do something with instance B, then instance A needs a reference to instance B.  Whoever creates instance A should give that the instance of B.  Who or how depends entirely on your code and how instances are created.

Comment: I am using an observableCollection only for a property that is being changed.

Comment: Also, the collection is chnaged in ViewModel2 and not in ViewModel1. That is causing me an issue. Since my ViewModel1 doesn't know that the collection is changed in ViewModel2, it never updates the view that is bound to ViewModel1

Comment: Why would it?  Nothing changes in 1, it changes in 2.  Whatever changes, it should be bound to the UI, and the UI should update automatically.  Sounds like you're doing something nonstandard, but that's completely unclear from the question.  A minimal example added to your question as an [edit] will help you get an answer. If you dump random code that doesn't have anything to do with your situation instead (e,g, the base class has nothing to do with anything) you're not going to get an answer :/

Comment: Will, I added more description. Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: Who creates the new InstitutionViewModel?  Who handles the Save and Cancel button clicks?  Whoever that is should be responsible for handing the InvestmentViewModel the new Institution, at which point it can be added to the list of institutions bound to the control, which then triggers UI updates via INPC/INCC.

Answer (score 0):

> trigger a PropertyChangednotification to a collection in view model of a UserControl1

Really don't overthink it...Put a method on the class for UserControl1 which will trigger the change. On the other control where the process originates, create a dependency property of UserControl's type and assign it in the XAML. Then when UserControl2 needs to do the operation, call usercontrol1 instance method.

---

> have to get a current instance of Investment UserControl while in the InstitutionViewModel. Is there any way, I can get that?

Place a `static` property of the VM on the app (`public partial class App` in the code). Then in the constructor of the VM have it look up the app and assign itself to that static. Then it can be gathered by anyone else.

---

Or create a flag dependency property on UserControl1 & UserControl2 and bind both controls to a shared Boolean using `TwoWay` binding.  When the Boolean changes from UserControl2 changing it, do the update in UserControl1.

Comment: OmegaMan, For the first approach, I will have to get a current instance of Investment UserControl while in the InstitutionViewModel. Is there any way, I can get that? Is there any place I can find an example somewhere. I am sure some other developers might have gone through similar situation as I do. I am very new to WPF and MVVM concept is also new to me.

Comment: @AndyJohnson I am of the belief that controls should not have VM's but all data should be done by dependency properties solely on the control. If you are not using Add to dependency properties due to learning/difficulty install these snippets (Ignore that they were designed for Silverlight, for they work in WPF and **still** use them) here [Helpful Silverlight Snippets - Jeff Wilcox](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/02/silverlight-snippets/)

Comment: OmegaMan, when I was watching a tutorial for MVVM, the instructor on youtube was creating a VM for each control and that is the reason, I staeted creating a VM for each user control. Can you please tell me the right way to create a VM (when and where? I know how..) and I think that is a cause of my issue, I looked at the important snippet site but can you point me to a usage of it... OR some example somewhere?

Comment: @AndyJohnson Some people take MVVM as dogma. It is really just Three Tiered Design. As long as you separate the View from the middle layer from the database, that is frankly all that matters. Putting MVVM on a control won't kill you and may make some sense for large controls. but I always felt (and coded) controls with just a code behind for simplicity. All business logic should be handled (or referenced when using ICommanding) on the main app VM. That's my opinion and I may be wrong. :-)